# Rails 5 get users_path(10) test doesn't fail even no "show" method defined in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Me gain, yes. Got a weird problem. This test should fail but it isn't.

Using Rails 5 --api only.

Got a UsersController like so:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    users = User.all
    render json: users
  end
end
```

Test file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "users should return list of users" do
    get users_path
    assert_response :success

    assert_not response.body.empty?
  end

  test "show valid id should return user json" do
    get users_path(10)
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

`Routes.rb` defined like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :cats
  resources :users
end
```

The console output:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 4176
Run options: --seed 28710

# Running:

........

Finished in 0.100764s, 79.3937 runs/s, 138.9390 assertions/s.

8 runs, 14 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Why is the test not reporting error when the controller clearly has no `show` method defined ?

Going to my browser localhost:3000/users/10 returns JSON saying "show" method does not exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Replace `users_path(10)` in the test to `user_path(10)`

Comment: Can you add your comment as answer please? I failed reading comprehension on this page real bad: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html I didn't notice the 's' is missing in the text explanation under section **2.3 Path and URL Helpers**

Comment: Happens. Specially if the 's' is there in the url but not in the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `users_path(10)` in the test with `user_path(10)`